# using unity physics with SteamVR

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, htc-vive, vrtk

I want to make a plank game in VR with Unity. So when the player walk outside of the plank, he falls. Right now the only way to make it work is by using VRTK which is another physics system and it makes a lot of things complicated.

I've put a rigidbody on the CameraRig and uncheck "is kinematic". The player falls, but the colliders on other objects are not working anymore...

Is there a way to use Unity's physics with SteamVR and without VRTK ??

Thank you !

Comment: Can you give a little more details about what is not working? Can you show the arborescence of your RigidBody and CameraRig?

Comment: Do You add collider on Camera Rig?

Comment: if you are not willing to use VRTK then please delete that and try your own code.  if you get stuck in any specific problem then ask question precisely

Comment: By the way VRTK is the best solution . You have tons of code and events i used this in different projects.

Comment: VRTK isn't a 'physics system' at all. May I ask why you regard it as making things more complicated? It simplifies a heck of a lot from my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I would read up on Rigidbodies and Colliders/Trigger Colliders - [here's a link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html).

Here's a useful table from that website:[image]

You will **need** to use this to understand why the player is falling. Is the `CameraRig` actually colliding with the ground? Is it a Trigger Collider (which has a callback method but doesn't do any physical collision). There's many possibilities for why.

I wrote a script that you can drag in two objects and see if they collide. You could use [that](https://github.com/KainosSoftwareLtd/ViveControllerToolkit/blob/master/CollisionCheckEditor.cs) if it helps.

The issue in VR with Vive is that determining where someone walks can be difficult, as we are only tracking their head and their hands. If you have a Vive Tracker available and it fits your use case you could use that to track someones foot.

What I have done in the past is use the `Camera(eyes)` GameObject within the `CameraRig` and get it's `transform.position.x` and `transform.position.z` value to determine if it has gone outside of the boundaries of the object the user is standing on.

Hope this helps,

Liam